# What is the meaning of "-e ." in requirements.txt in aws cdk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm following this [AWS CDK python getting started tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html) to learn how to use AWS CDK with python.

I'm curious about the meaning of `-e .` in `requirements.txt` file, which is generated by AWS CDK. What does it mean?

The document from `pip install --help` says `-e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.`.

I don't think the `-e` in requirements.txt means `--editable`. It must represents something different.

I cannot find any explanations about `-e .` in requirements.txt in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files.

What does `-e .` mean in `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [document](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/developer/getting-started-with-the-aws-cloud-development-kit-and-python/) says

> requirements.txt—This file is used by pip to install all of the dependencies for your application. In this case, it contains only -e . This tells pip to install the requirements specified in setup.py. It also tells pip to run

So it tells pip to install the requirements specified in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 13):

Python applications generally have a `requirements.txt` file and a `setup.py` file.

`requirements.txt` is a plain text file that lists down the python package requirements.

`setup.py` is a python script that uses `setuptools` to define a package. `setup.py` also contains the list of dependencies to be installed along with all the other metadata about the package.

If you define your dependencies in both places this is a redundancy. `-e .` is the way you can overcome this problem. You can just define your dependencies in `setup.py` alone and create `requirements.txt` file with just `-e .` in it.

You can now use `pip install -r requirements.txt` without defining all the dependencies again in the requirements file. All the packages in `setup.py` are automatically installed, `setup.py` becomes your single source of truth for what dependencies are to be installed.