# Error during pip install -r requirements.txt due to "-e ."

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, requirements.txt, install-requires

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install the dependencies for my Python project using **`pip install -r requirements.txt`**.

The error I'm receiving: It's due to -e . present in **`requirements.txt`**

> ```
>   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
>   │ exit code: 1
>   ╰─> [3 lines of output]
>       error in ML_Project setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected package name at the start of dependency specifier
>           -e .
>           ^
>       [end of output]
>
>   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
> ╰─> See above for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details
> ```

and this is what my **`requirements.txt`** looks like:

> ```
> pandas
> numpy
> seaborn
>
> -e .
> ```

this is my **`setup.py`**:

> ```py
> from setuptools import setup, find_packages
> from typing import List
>
> HYPEN_E_DOT = "-e ."
>
> def get_requirements(file_path: str) -> List[str]:
>     '''
>     This function will return the list of requirements from the requirements.txt file
>     '''
>     requirements = []
>     with open(file_path) as file_obj:
>         requirements = file_obj.readlines()
>         requirements = [req.replace("\n", " ") for req in requirements]
>
>         if HYPEN_E_DOT in requirements:
>             requirements.remove(HYPEN_E_DOT)
>
>     return requirements
>     
>
> setup(
> name='ML_Project',
> version='0.0.1',
> author='author',
> author_email= 'author@gmail.com',
> packages=find_packages(),
> install_requires= get_requirements('requirements.txt')
>
> )
> ```

I looked the solution online but everywhere it suggests to remove "-e ."
I want to keep "-e ." in **setup.py**.

Comment: Why do you want to have "-e ." in your requirements.txt?

Comment: Don't know I am beginner following a tutorial. In tutorial instructor said that if you run 'requirements.txt' with '-e .' in it and run 'pip install -r requirements.txt' then setup.py will also be able to run. He said '-e .' maps requiremetns.txt to setup.py

Comment: Just remove the "-e ." and I would check out the top answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073540/what-is-the-meaning-of-e-in-requirements-txt-in-aws-cdk

Comment: When `req.replace("\n", " ")` happens, it ends up replacing `-e .\n` with `-e . `, notice the trailing empty space. Then it gets compared to `HYPEN_E_DOT = "-e ."` which does not have the trailing empty space. So `if HYPEN_E_DOT in requirements` is never true.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically coming because in requirements.txt file you have placed a traling extra space after "-e .". remove that extra space and it will work perfectly.